# java 17 - reflection to use methods in external jar files - Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible

Tags: java, reflection, java-11, java-17

I've this code below which is used to load methods defined in some external `jar` files and in the web application using Spring Boot 2.7.10 version, it can invoke these external methods at run time.

This works fine with java 11, but when upgraded to java 17, it has error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @221af3c0
```

```
    private static void addToClassPath(String jarFilePath) {
        try {
            File file = new File(jarFilePath);
            if (!(file.exists() && file.canRead())) {
                throw new UdfDirectoryNotAccessibleException(jarFilePath);
            }
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) UdfInvoker.class.getClassLoader();
            Class urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;
            Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});

            // error here since java 17
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[] { url });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new UdfFailedLoadingException(jarFilePath, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new UdfJarFileNotAccessibleException(jarFilePath, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how this code can work with java 17 or if it can change to use something else which can work with both java 11 and java 17? Thanks.

**NOTE:**

- Adding arguments to JDK is not an option as I cannot change that in servlet container Tomcat or JRE of development machine.
- Downgrade java version to 11 is also not an option.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why not just add that .jar file to the classpath when running the program?

Comment: @VGR That code (I got from other team member) is used to load .jar files to classpath when running the program.

Comment: If this is running in Tomcat, why not just add the .jar file to WEB-INF/lib in your .war file?

Comment: @BằngRikimaru: you're digging deep into the classloader internals that are not documented and not guaranteed to ever be stable. Sometimes that breaks. As others, I *strongly* advise you to find another way to load that class (maybe by instantiating a *new* `URLClassLoader` with the appropriate parent, that usage is actually supported!). And if you choose to ignore that advice, then look if the appropriate `--add-opens` parameters to your Java launcher call can help.

Comment: @VGR the .jar files are created by external users, they don't exist in my .war file at build time. When the web application starts, it tried to load these .jar files from users and then the users can use them.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks for the advice, I didn't develop the code though. This is unfamiliar to me, I couldn't add the extra parameter to JDK so this needs to do another workaround.

Comment: I assume each of these user-provided .jar files needs to have at least one class which implements a known interface (or extends a known abstract class), so your program knows what to call.  If this is the case, [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) is probably the correct, approved, and safe way to accomplish your task.

Comment: @VGR thanks,  I will have a look about ServiceLoader tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [VGR user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr), I managed to make it work with these steps below using `ServiceLoader` from JDK 1.6:

First, in the project code I create a file call `Service`

```
package test
public interface Service {
    
    public Result handle(List<Result> paramList);
    
}
```

Then, I create a separated java file out of the project code which will be built as external java file

```
package implement
import test.Service;
public class ServiceImp implements Service {
  
    public Result handle(List<Result> paramList) {
        // write code here
    }

}
```

Then, I build the jar file for `implement.jar` which contains `SeviceImp.class`.

NOTE: in this jar file, it must contain this file path
`META-INF/services/test.Service` and the file contains `test.ServiceImp`.

In the project code, I have this method to load the given `implement.jar` file.

```
            URL[] urls = new URL[] { file.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL()};
            ClassLoader parent = UdfInvoker.class.getClassLoader();
            URLClassLoader c = new URLClassLoader(urls, parent);
            
            ServiceLoader<Service> sl = ServiceLoader.load(Service.class, c);
            Iterator<Service> apit = sl.iterator();
            while (apit.hasNext()) {
                // Here you can store it to a list to reuse later or call it directly 
                apit.next().handle(new ArrayList<>());
```

Answer (score -4):

if you don't mind using unsafe reflection you can replace the call to "setAccesible" with:

```
Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
((Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null)).putBoolean(method, 12, true);
```